# Android image popup message

Tags: android, browser, popup, ads

Please I'm actually coding an app for Android and I need some help to do something. I need to do a kind of popup image message exactly like that : http://postimg.org/image/ovaqw14n5/ I want that picture to be clicked and then it open the browser to open the link integrated with this image

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should use a [transparent, dialog themed activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176922/how-to-create-transparent-activity-in-android). It will use a layout with a FramLayout containing an ImageView and a themed button.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply set it to a new intent which opens this popup screen followed by an intent shift back to the activity when the "x" is clicked on.

Also, using a FrameLayout + imageView and a button (x) you can create this simply in the .xml.

Comment: This is my style.xml source code                               <resources>

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light" />
  
</resources>                                                         can you please give me the final source code using a FrameLayout + imageView and a button (x)?  Thanks